# white circle in microsoft SQL server management studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new in SQL server management studio 2012

now i'm use data from server and it has a white circle on my database

4 people in my team use this server and everyone see that...

we use same ID to login to this server...

[image]

what does it's mean

please help me...

Answer (score 44):

The white circle usually contains a green arrow, a blue paused symbol, or a red square - indicating that the SQL Server service is either running, paused, or stopped respectively.

Usually security is set-up so that only administrators can see the service status, so regular users don't have access to that information, hence why SSMS displays an empty white circle, meaning the service is in an indeterminate state, from its viewpoint - of course if you can connect to the service and run queries then it has to be running, so don't worry about this.

See here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic825246-146-1.aspx

Comment: SSMS uses WMI to query the server status. If everything is as it should (services running etc.) and you still dont see the green arrow, you may need additional permissions on the server. A local administrator should see the green arrow. More info in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/08/21/service-status-watcher-in-sql-server-management-studio-how-it-works/

Comment: [Related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/greyed-out-menu-options-broken-activity-monitor/)

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with the firewall nor SQL Server Browser services.  By default SQL Server is going to listen on port 1433 unless you change it.  If the port was blocked, you would not be able to access the instance.

SQL Server browser listens for incoming requests, again, if disabled, you would not be able to connect remotely to the server.

The status bubble is caused by a permissions issue.  Easy way to troubleshoot, close Management Studio, right click, it and run as administrator.  If the status shows up, you have a permissions issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The way I solved it was by registering the server: Right-click your instance, click register..., and type the relevant information. Re-connect.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio uses WMI to query for information about the status of the services.

> If it’s a local machine, then make sure you are using “Run as administrator” option. and check if sure “Windows Management
>   Instrumentation” service is running under services.msc on the server.
>
> check that if the firewall is not blocking WMI communication. 
>       Now, Run WMI query to make sure we are able to query services. Below are the steps.
>
> ```
> 1. Start > Run > WBEMTest
> 2. Click on Connect and provide below (change Remote Machine Name and ComputerManagement<Number> based on SQL version.
> \\{servername}\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement13
> 3>Click Connect
> 4>Click on Query
> 5>Type Select * from SQLService and Apply. You should see the results.
> ```
>
> If you have a problem with above that it's confirmed WMI issue.
>
> Make sure that you are able to open SQL Server Configuration Manager, which uses WMI.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in SQL server 2014 and I followed below steps to resolve it

```
1. Access SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Under SQL Server Services, start the SQL Server Agent(make sure the start mode is automatic).
```

After starting, red alert on sql server agent went away also got green play icon on DB server.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to restart SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to get the status to show up again.

Answer (score -2):

This is for new users. if you are facing the same problem then better to start the Sql Browser services manually, check for the user access rights, check whether the required ports are enabled or not. any of the solution can help...

Answer (score -3):

You have to enable all required ports on firewall ;)

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question.