# SQL Server Management Studio Database Icons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We are currently having some database issues and are trying to determine the cause. When I went into SSMS one of the DB instances was showing this red icon over it. Can someone please explain to me the meaning of these icons? It keeps switching from red to green then back again and we have heard that everything is running slow.

[image: Database Icons]

Comment: Expand Management, SQL server logs and check for events

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710016/white-circle-in-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Comment: This isn't about programming, so SO isn't the place. That said, I'd change my close vote to a dupe for the one _jpw_ linked if I could. More simply, the icons are using standard colours and shapes to indicate 'play'/'running' and 'stop'/'stopped' states. And yeah, checking the event log is the first thing to do; it sounds like you're one of the database admins, so get familiar with the basic administrative tools!

Comment: [That's not what the Help Center says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) @underscore_d, nor has it been SO policy since the beginning: _"Stack Overflow is for... people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is 
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_ SSMS is a software tool commonly used by Programmers.

Comment: Thank you @Ben for the clarification on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first icon means that you have no Windows rights to start/stop the service.

The second means that your Windows account does have rights to start/stop the service and that the service is running.

The third means that your Windows account does have rights to start/stop the service and that the service is stopped.